# How to send Gatsby-Image to component as property

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've been trying to figure out how to use Gatsby-image with components and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using Gatsby-image, gatsby-transformer-sharp, gatsby-plugin-sharp.

**Here's my query:**

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    imageOne: file(relativePath: { eq: "tbbs1.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**and using it like this works fine as many tutorials show:**

`<Img fluid={props.data.imageOne.childImageSharp.fluid} />`

**Here is the component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import Img from "gatsby-image";


export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
  }
  next() {
    this.slider.slickNext();
  }
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      lazyLoad: 'progressive',
      arrows: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    let slides = this.props.bilder.map( (item, index) =>
      (
        <div key={index} className="slide-container">
          <div className="slider-box" onClick={this.next}>
            <img src={this.props.bilder[index]} alt=""/>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    );

    return (
      <div id="work" className="slick-container">
        <div className="title-desc-container">
          <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
          <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
        </div>
        <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
          {slides}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**but what I'd like to do is something like this:**

`<SimpleSlider title="title" desc="description" images={[props.data.imageOne.childImageSharp.fluid, props.data.imageTwo.childImageSharp.fluid]} />`

I'm guessing there's an easy solution for this, but I haven't found it yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show you SimpleSlider component code?

Comment: I've added the component code now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. You are using the HTML tag `<img />`. You have to use `<Img />` component from `gatsby-image` to make it work (you are importing it, but you are not using it).
2. You are not passing any `bilder` prop to your component but you are trying to call it in your `SimpleSlider` component. Just map your `images` props and it's enough. (Or pass the desired `bilder` prop)

Refactor your `SimpleSlider` as follow:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import Img from "gatsby-image";


export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
  }
  next() {
    this.slider.slickNext();
  }
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      lazyLoad: 'progressive',
      arrows: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    return (
      <div id="work" className="slick-container">
        <div className="title-desc-container">
          <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
          <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
        </div>
        <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
          {this.props.images.map((image, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="slide-container">
              <div className="slider-box" onClick={this.next}>
                <Img src={image} style={{width: 200, height: 200}}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, I forgot to change that part back when I went back to copy the component. I had previously tried with <Img> but it did not work.
2. What do you mean I'm not passing props (btw bilder is Norwegian for images)?
This is what I used to do before 
`import food1 from '../images/foodsense1.jpg'`
`<SimpleSlider title="FoodSense" desc="App design, Logo" bilder={[food1, food2, food3]} />`
and `<img src={this.props.bilder[index]} alt=""/>`
If I could do this without running a query, I'd be more than happy to do that, but afaik you can only use Gatsby-img with GraphQL.

Comment: 1. <Img> is the only way to consume the images with Gatsby, 2. it doesn't matter if you call it bilder or images but it has to be the same prop name in both component. You can't import that way the images in Gatsby... Did you try the code I posted?  Use that code for your SimpleSlider and pass the images using the GraphQL query, it will work